# What is the most efficient way to tell if a string of unicode characters has unique characters in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, hashmap, unique

If it was just ASCII characters I just use array of bool of size 256. But Unicode has so many characters. 
 1. Wikipedia says unicode has more than 110000 characters. So bool[110000] might not be a good idea?
 2. Lets say the characters are coming in a stream and I just want to stop whenever a duplicate is detected. How do I do this?
 3. Since the set is so big, I was thinking hash table. But how do I tell when the collision happens because I do not want to continue once a collision is detected. Is there a way to do this in STL implementation of hash table?

Efficient in terms of speed and memory utilization.

Comment: How big is your expected data (to be checked)? Do you expect not-unique cases often or not? Is the data somewhat normal text in some language or more "nonsense" numbers taken out of Unicode (ie. characters which don´t make a readable text together)?

Comment: lets say there is a stream of data coming in and it contains all the characters from unicode, Even the nonsensical ones. And a repeating character could appear anywhere in the stream but I want to know how to tackle it if it appears after some 100000 characters. I do not expect repeatations often. This question is purely to see what methods are suitable. It has nothing to do with the realistic data. @deviantfan

Comment: `bool[110000]` is only 107KB in size. Modern systems have GBs of RAM, and even the default maximum thread stack size is typically set to at least 1MB (9x larger than the array).  So I think you can afford to allocate a measly 107KB.  If you are worried about overflowing the stack, allocate it on the heap instead.

Comment: I guess using an array of bool should not be a problem. I was just looking whether C++ has something like "hashtable.contains()" in its STL implementation or anything close to it. I guess it does not.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your Options

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. `bool[0x110000]` (note that this is a hex constant, not a decimal constant as in the question)
2. `vector<bool>` with a size of `0x110000`
3. sorted `vector<uint32_t>` or `list<uint32_t>` containing every encountered codepoint
4. `map<uint32_t, bool>` or `unordered_map<uint32_t, bool>` containing a mapping of codepoints to whether they have been encountered
5. `set<uint32_t>` or `unordered_set<uint32_t>` containing every encountered codepoint
6. A custom container, e.g. a [bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) which provides high-density probabilistic storage for exactly this kind of problem

#### Analysis

Now, let's perform a basic analysis of the 6 variants:

1. Requires exactly `0x110000` bytes = 1.0625 MiB plus whatever overhead a single allocation does. Both setting and testing is extremely fast.
2. While it would seem that this is pretty exactly the same solution, it only requires roughly 1/8 of the memory, since it will store the bools in one *bit* each instead of one *byte* each. Both setting and testing are extremely fast, performance relative to the first solution may be better or worse, depending on things like cpu cache size, memory performance and of course your test data.
3. While potentially taking the least amount of memory (4 bytes per encountered codepoint, so it will require less memory as long as the input stream contains at most 0x110000 / 8 / 4 = 34816), performance for this solution will be abysmal: Testing takes O(log(n)) for the vector (binary search) and O(n) for the list (binary search requires random access), while inserting takes O(n) for the vector (all following elements must be moved) and O(1) for the list (assuming that you kept the result of your failed test). This means, that a test + insert cycles takes O(n). Therefore your total runtime will be O(n^2)...
4. Without doing a lot of talking about this, it should be obvious that we do not need the `bool`, but would rather just test for existence, leading to solution 5.
5. Both sets are fairly similar in performance, `set` is usually implemented with a binary tree and `unordered_set` with a hash map. This means, that both are fairly inefficient memory wise: Both contain additional overhead (non-leaf nodes in trees and the actual tables containing the hashes in hashmaps) meaning they will probably take 8-16 bytes per entry. Testing and Inserting are O(log(n)) for the `set` and O(1) amortized for the `unordered_set`.
   To answer the comment, testing whether `uint32 const x` is contained in `unordered_set<uint32_t> data` is done like so: `if(data.count(x))` or `if(data.find(x) != data.end())`.
6. The major drawbacks here is a significant amount of work that the developer has to invest. Also, the bloom filter that was given as an example is a probabilistic data structure, meaning false-positives are possible (false negatives are not in this specific case).

#### Conclusion

Since your test data is not actual textual data, using a set of either kind is actually very memory inefficient (with high probability). Since this is also the only possibility to achieve better performance than the naive solutions 1 and 2, it will in all probability be significantly slower as well.

Taking into consideration the fact that it is easier to handle and that you seem to be fairly conscious of memory consumption, the final verdict is that `vector<bool>` seems the most appropriate solution.

#### Notes

Unicode is intended to represent text. This means that your test case and any analysis following from this is probably highly flawed.

Also, while it is simple to detect duplicate *code points*, the idea of a *character* is far more ambiguous, and may require some kind of normalization (e.g. "ä" can be either [one codepoint](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e4/index.htm) or an "[a](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/61/index.htm)" and a [diacritical mark](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0300.pdf), or even be based on the [cyrillic "a"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0430/index.htm)).